# How to fix this problems in C

Tags: c

I've been teaching myself C for a few months when I have time, and I have run into a problem I am not sure how to fix.

Specifically, when I try to compile this using gcc, I get:

RastgeleKarakter.c files

```
RastgeleKarakter RastgeleKarakterOlustur(){

    RastgeleKarakter this;
    this=(RastgeleKarakter)malloc(sizeof(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER));
    this->rnd=RandomKur();
    this->TekKarakter=&TekKarakter;
    this->FazlaKarakter=&FazlaKarakter;
    this->AraKarakter=&AraKarakter;
    this->Arama=&Arama;
    this->BelirlenenKarakter=&BelirlenenKarakter;
    return this;
}

void TekKarakter(){
    int mod;
    mod = (saniye()%52);
    printf(Dizi[mod]);
    printf('\n');
}
```

RastgeleKarakter.h files

```
struct RASTGELEKARAKTER{

    Random rnd;
    char (*RastgeleKarakterOlustur)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);
    char (*TekKarakter)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*);
    char* (*FazlaKarakter)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*, int);
    char* (*AraKarakter)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*, char, char, int);
    char (*Arama)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*, char[], char);
    char* (*BelirlenenKarakter)(struct RASTGELEKARAKTER*, char, char, char, char, char, char, int);
};

typedef struct RASTGELEKARAKTER* RastgeleKarakter;
char RastgeleKarakterOlustur(const RastgeleKarakter);
char TekKarakter(const RastgeleKarakter);
char* FazlaKarakter(const RastgeleKarakter, int);
char* AraKarakter(const RastgeleKarakter, char, char, int);
char Arama(const RastgeleKarakter, char[], char);
char* BelirlenenKarakter(const RastgeleKarakter, char, char, char, char, char, char, int);
```

> ```
> ./src/RastgeleKarakter.c:26:21: error: conflicting types for 'RastgeleKarakterOlustur'
>     RastgeleKarakter RastgeleKarakterOlustur()
>
> In file included from ./src/RastgeleKarakter.c:14:0:
> ./include/RastgeleKarakter.h:35:7: note: previous declaration of 'RastgeleKarakterOlustur' was here
>   char RastgeleKarakterOlustur(const RastgeleKarakter);                                                                        
>
>
> ./src/RastgeleKarakter.c:38:9: error: conflicting types for 'TekKarakter'
>     void TekKarakter()
>
> In file included from ./src/RastgeleKarakter.c:14:0:
> ./include/RastgeleKarakter.h:36:7: note: previous declaration of 'TekKarakter' was here
>   char TekKarakter(const RastgeleKarakter);
>
>
> ./src/RastgeleKarakter.c:49:9: error: conflicting types for 'FazlaKarakter'
>     void FazlaKarakter(int Sayi)
>
>
> In file included from ./src/RastgeleKarakter.c:14:0:
> ./include/RastgeleKarakter.h:37:8: note: previous declaration of 'FazlaKarakter' was here
>   char* FazlaKarakter(const RastgeleKarakter, int);
>
>
> ./src/RastgeleKarakter.c:62:9: error: conflicting types for 'AraKarakter'
>     void AraKarakter(char a, char b, int Sayi)
> ```

Comment: you need to add an include statement at the start of your file to include the .h file.

Comment: Inconsequential for this problem, but do avoid typedef'ing pointers and casting the return of `malloc()` if possible.

Comment: The function signatures don't match between your `.c` and `.h` files.  For example: `RastgeleKarakter RastgeleKarakterOlustur()` != `char RastgeleKarakterOlustur(const RastgeleKarakter)`.

Comment: You might also consider adding a preprocessor guard to your .h files.

Answer (score 2):

Because in `RastgeleKarakter.h` you declared

`char RastgeleKarakterOlustur(const RastgeleKarakter);`

and in `RastgeleKarakter.c` you defined

`RastgeleKarakter RastgeleKarakterOlustur() {...}`

They are of same function name, but with different signature. You may consider to change one of them.

Comment: Thank you I have deleted that line.